# How to remove specific item from existed minecraft world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

Well, I have kind'a funny issue. I have my modded minecraft server (about 120 mods installed) and some world on it I've played a lot.  I decided to add new mod - `OreSpawn`. When I added it I faced a lot of id conflicts. The thing is that `OreSpawn` has fixed base block id and other block ids are generated depending on this base block id value. So I had to dump all available block ids using `NEI`, then I selected the widest id range to fit all ~400 blocks from `OreSpawn`, changed base block id value so I had only two id conflicts in result. Those two conflicted items are from `AppliedEnergistics`. One of them is `null` item, I'm not quite sure what it is. The second one is **tiny tnt**. So i decided change tiny tnt id in `AppliedEnergistics.config` file. As you can guess this will change all existed **tiny tnts** in my world to something from `OreSpawn`. The funniest thing is that this *"something"* is block called **"random dungeon spawner"** and it generates gigantic dungeons/castles with tons of really nasty and hardcore mobs in places where my AE system, chests and basically all home was. I tried to downgrade my mod pack, find all those **tiny tnt** blocks in game and void them, but still I face this issue. Apparently, there are some chests in dungeons near my home with this item inside. So my question is - **how can i find all those items with specific id in the world?**... and remove them?

Comment: I think you could use MCEDIT, not sure how though..

Comment: @DatEpicCoderGuyWhoPrograms, I've tried MCEdit already but can't find any similar option - select by id, delete by id or smthing.

Answer (score 4):

MCEdit can to this, according to this [forum post](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/90855-solved-remove-mod-generated-blocks/). You can replace all blocks of a specific ID with another (e.g. Air).

> Press <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd>, and select your entire map. Then press <kbd>4</kbd>, then <kbd>R</kbd>. Then put in IDs.

Answer (score 2):

It's really easy, all you need to do is install this mod called "idfix" which will automaticly re-write all the IDs for each block so there are no conflicts.. if you install a new mod, also reinstall idfix! It's easy, I used it for my mod pack!